# Automatically adding space after comma when save on changes VSCode

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I have this code (t,s) but when I save on changes it turns into (t, s) which adds space after the comma. How can I prevent VScode from automatically adding this space?

Comment: perhaps you use a linter and you have set a rule?

Comment: Oh I have fixed this, it is because of an extension that has been deprecated. Thank you

Comment: @Vulearntocode hello welcome to stack overflow! please can you describe what you have done?

Comment: I just have to uninstall the extension which is "HTML snippet" and everything is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > Javascript > Code Style > Formatting

Turn off `Automatically format when typing`